# Vue 3: StopHandle for computed()?

Tags: vuejs3

In Vue 3, watchEffect() and watch() returns StopHandle which allows the caller to stop watching.

I think that computed() should have a kind of StopHandle since computed() uses (it's my guess) a kind of 'watch' internally to track dirtiness, but there is none.

Is there a reason that computed() has no StopHandle-like thing? Or is there a function that works similarly to StopHandle?

Thanks.

Comment: You set a dependency in a computed, why would you want to stop making things reactive there? Just don't update the dependency.

Comment: @kissu Maybe there would be a case when computed()s are dynamically created and managed.

Comment: If you don't use your computed anywhere, it will not be re-calculated

Comment: @Duannx I don't worry about re-calculation. What I worry about is the 'watch' part of computed(). That is - if it is dynamically created and removed, the watch part can remain in the 'watch list' and cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [effectScope](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#effectscope) to manually dispose effects like `computed` or `watch` like this:

```js
const scope = effectScope()

scope.run(() => {
  const doubled = computed(() => counter.value * 2)

  watch(doubled, () => console.log(doubled.value))

  watchEffect(() => console.log('Count: ', doubled.value))
})

// to dispose all effects in the scope
scope.stop()
```

An unofficial way is calling the `stop` function directly from the computed variable:

```js
const doubled = computed(() => counter.value * 2)
doubled.effect.stop()
```